# Error while accessing Azure Ad through Graph Api

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory

But i am getting below error while calling code sample to get users from Azure AD

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.)
 ---> Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.ThrowIfFailedResponse(HttpResponseMessage response, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, Activity activityForAttributes)
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.SendAsync[ModelType](RequestInformation requestInfo, ParsableFactory`1 factory, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.SendAsync[ModelType](RequestInformation requestInfo, ParsableFactory`1 factory, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.Users.UsersRequestBuilder.GetAsync(Action`1 requestConfiguration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Xlp.Domain.Services.GraphService1.GetAllUsersAsync() in C:\Users\Shashikantpawar\Desktop\XLP\backend\src\XLP.Domain\Services\GraphService1.cs:line 26
   at Xlp.Api.Controllers.ClientsController.Get() in C:\Users\Shashikantpawar\Desktop\XLP\backend\src\Xlp.Api\Controllers\V1\ClientsController.cs:line 40
   at lambda_method5(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:5224
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.4
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Postman-Token: 2bb4e39a-686e-4072-af4f-9c85b3760bc2
```

Tried below code sample
Expectation - To get the users details

```
public async Task<List<Microsoft.Graph.Models.User>> GetAllUsersAsync()

        {

            var clientId = _configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ClientId");

            var tenantId = _configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:TenantId");

            var clientSecret = _configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ClientSecret");




            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId,     clientSecret);

            GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);




            var users = graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync().Result;

            return users.Value;




        }
```

Comment: You have a two port application.  The first port is the client to the server.  The second port is the connection from server to the database.  The error indicates the second port is failing to get the OData in the server Controller.   Most likely reason is the connection is failing from server to database.  One reason could be the authentication. or the connection string from server to database is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to check the following code to receive data of current user.

Code used:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using active_directory_aspnetcore_webapp_openidconnect_v2.Models;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;

namespace active_directory_aspnetcore_webapp_openidconnect_v2.Controllers
{

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
      

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger,
                          GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        }

        
        [Authorize]
         public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
         {
            //var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            var user =  _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync().Result;
            ViewData["ApiResult"] = user.DisplayName;
             ViewData["Givenname"] = user.GivenName;
    return View();
         }

…

}
```

Received error because of use of **`.GetAsync().Result`**;  when using `asynchronous` statement.

[image]

```
**AggregateException:** One or more errors occurred. (Code: generalException Message: An error occurred sending the request. )
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.get_Result()
active_directory_aspnetcore_webapp_openidconnect_v2.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in HomeController.cs

  var user =  _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

Here in the code if you observe you are using Async in the controller action but await is not used , instead .Result is used which is leading to `deadlock conditon`.

With the following code where await is used, it works well for in my case:

```
    [Authorize]
     public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
     {
        var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
        ViewData["ApiResult"] = user.DisplayName;
         ViewData["Givenname"] = user.GivenName;
return View();
     }
```

[image]

So check by using:

**`var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync();`**

[image]

Comment: Checked above this error is not related to async code issue

Comment: Have you tried giving scopes to graph . `var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };`     and check if User.Read.All delegated and application permissions are granted . Make sure the client secret is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The error message Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError is very generic and it can happen for multiple reasons. It can happen if the Client ID is wrong, or if the Client Secret has expired, amongst various other reasons.
To solve the problem, you should first check what is the error message you are getting. Put a try-catch around your graph API call and use the ODataError object as shown below:

```
try
{
   var users = graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync().Result;
}
catch (ODataError odataError)
{
   log.Debug(string.Format("Error Code: {0}", odataError.Error.Code));
   log.Debug(string.Format("Error Message: {0}", odataError.Error.Message));
   throw;
}
```

With the help of this error code and error message you can research further. More information [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#error-handling).